# org.hibernate.AnnotationException:A Foreign key refering x from y has the wrong number of column. should be n

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

the following exception happens during hibernate initialisation:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.maar.projectbuilder.domain.Language from com.maar.projectbuilder.domain.ItemInfo has the wrong number of column. should be 0
```

[image: I have the tables as in the screenshot above]

I have the tables as in the screenshot above.
Entity classes are written as below.

```
public class ItemInfo implements Serializable {

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @Id
   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", nullable = false)
   private Item itemId;

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Language.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "language_item_id", nullable = false)
   private Language languageItemId;

   @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
   private Integer type;
   //getters,setters,constructors
}
```

another one

```
public class Language implements Serializable {
   @Column(name = "isDefault")
   private Integer isDefault;

   @Column(name = "abbr")
   private String abbr;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @Id
   @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
   @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
   private Item itemId;
}
```

my item entity

```
public class Item implements Serializable {
   @Column(name = "c4i")
   private String c4i;

   @Column(name = "status")
   private Integer status=1;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Integer id;
}
```

How could I resolve this. What am I missing?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The @OneToMany relation in Language to itemInfo is missing. Please add them and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy News :)

I added **referencedColumnName** param to **JoinColumn** annotation and thats working fine now !

Last Entity looking like this.

```
public class ItemInfo implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", nullable = false)
    private Item itemId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "language_item_id",**referencedColumnName = "item_id"**)
    private Language languageItemId;

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    private Integer type;
}
```

Thanks Everybody. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

In your E-R diagram, item_info use join primary key:item_id,language_item_id and type, but in your mapping, you just mapped item_id